# L8 - Make a FormRequest from another FormRequest fails

Tags: validation, laravel-8, laravel-formrequest

I've a simple code (more o less) like this.

Routes:

```
Route::post('car', 'CarController@store')->name('insert_car.store');
Route::post('car-italian', 'CarItalianController@store')->name('insert_car-italian.store');
```

Controllers:

```
class CarController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreCarRequest $request)
    {
        return Car::create($request->validated()) // Calling 'car-italian' route, the code fails here!
    }
}
class CarItalianController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreCarItalianRequest $request)
    {
        $input_parameters = $request->validated();
        $t = [
            'model' => $input_parameters['modello'],
            'door' => $input_parameters['porte'],
        ];
        return (new CarController)->store(new StoreCarRequest($t));
    }
}
```

Forms Request:

```
class StoreCarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'model' => 'string',
            'door'  => 'integer'
        ];
    }
}
class StoreCarItalianRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'modello' => 'string',
            'porte'   => 'integer'
        ];
    }
}
```

When I call the route `car-italian`, It fails with message:

```
Call to a member function validated() on null
```

Can someone help me? I spent one full day on it :-/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution updating the Controller `CarItalianController`:

```
class CarController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreCarRequest $request)
    {
        return Car::create($request->validated()) 
    }
}
class CarItalianController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreCarItalianRequest $request)
    {
        $input_parameters = $request->validated();
        $t = [
            'model' => $input_parameters['modello'],
            'door' => $input_parameters['porte'],
        ];

        $insertRequest = new StoreCarRequest();
        $insertRequest->setValidator(Validator::make($t, $insertRequest->rules()));
        return (new CarController)->store($insertRequest);
    }
}
```